# I am using pycharm and cloud run plugin to deploy flask app to GCP on a Mac M1 and am getting exec format errors (only in cloud)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, google-cloud-run, apple-m1

The code is the hello world app that comes with pycharm for flask apps, very simple build.  When deploying to the local test container all is fine, when deploying to Cloud Run it builds a container locally and pushes it to the google repository (error free and seemingly ok) but fails when it tries to deploy in the end with an error

> {
> "textPayload": "terminated: Application failed to start: Failed to create init process: failed to load /usr/local/bin/python: exec format error",
> "insertId": "605e2de200094a2b42066c2b",
> "resource": {
> "type": "cloud_run_revision",
> "labels": {
> "revision_name": "insight-sync-00017-wur",
> "service_name": "insight-sync",
> "location": "europe-west2",
> "configuration_name": "insight-sync",
> "project_id": "insights-307616"
> }
> },
> "timestamp": "2021-03-26T18:54:26.608749033Z",
> "severity": "ERROR",
> "labels": {
> "instanceId": "00bf4bf02d2807cc6001caa2eabfd154d00fbbfa3fb6b2b2e32d286040ae12bb7480bdaf6f72d62a612cc98c55abd3364155aec51e087180851f0c02bd"
> },
> "logName": "projects/insights-307616/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
> "receiveTimestamp": "2021-03-26T18:54:26.613237692Z"
> }

If i launch the image locally (on the M1) from the docker dashboard and connect to it via terminal, the /usr/bin/local/python loads fine which indicates to me that the container or environment is not suitable for GCP itself but works on the M1.

I've looked a bit at buildx but am stuck with how to integrate that into the pycharm and GCP cloud run plugin...   any assistance would be greatly appreciated in how to get past this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Docker image that you are running locally on your macOS is for ARM processors.
 Cloud Run provides Intel processors. Review this article for multi-CPU containers, but I have not tested this with Cloud Run. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/

Comment: Thanks John.  Buildx looks like the right direction.  The thing i cannot figure out is how to get the "cloud code" plugin (that handles the build and deployment steps for GCP / Cloud Run) to use it.  The alternative would be to build using buildx and push to the multi architecture image to the google repository (which i may try tomorrow) by hand.  A bit of a long work around when all i really need is to get the plugin to use buildx (or get docker to automatically use it for builds).  I appreciate your information and i'm still hoping something else will pop up.  Thanks

Comment: Tip: you can build the container locally using Docker and then push the container image to Google Cloud Repository. Then you can deploy the GCR image to Cloud Run. Cloud Run uses gVisor to run containers, so I am not sure if multi-architecture containers are supported. https://gvisor.dev/

Comment: Yep that did it.  I tried first with "docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t username/progect:latest --push ." and then, pulled it, tagged it and pushed it to GCP....  this failed (for the reason you mentioned)....  BUT when i rebuilt it with the single --platform of linux/amd64 magic happend and it worked....   so i have a very inelegant, but working solution....  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to John Hanley for the lead...  The problem was that the docker image generated was for ARM and GCP required an AMD image.  And there was no way to tell the pyCharm "Cloud Code" plugin to build for that when deploying to the cloud.

In the end the solution was to do all the testing locally and then deploy using the following commands in sequence...  replace "docker_user/dockerproject" with your own credentials and "gcrname/project" with your gcr names:

do this once

> docker buildx create --name mybuilder
>
> docker buildx use mybuilder
>
> docker buildx inspect --bootstrap

(from [docker_docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/))

Then from the working directory for a build and deploy do:

> docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t docker_user/dockerproject:latest --push .
>
> (very important, while buildx lets you make multi architecture builds by specifying multiple items after --platform you do not want to to this if deploying to GCP....   GCP does not run these, so only specify one platform.  This will mean that the container will not run on your M1 mac, but you can build a different copy for testing, so not a big deal)
>
> docker buildx imagetools inspect docker_user/dockerproject:latest
>
> docker pull docker_user/dockerproject:latest
>
> docker tag docker_user/dockerproject:latest gcr.io/gcrname/project
>
> docker push gcr.io/gcrname/project

(from [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) )

(this command will note that it is pushing to gcr - you may need to set auth credentials for this in docker - another topic)

And finally:

(you can get this command by attempting to deploy via cloudrun in pyCharm, it is much nicer than the interactive process from the registry page in GCP admin)....

> gcloud run deploy  --quiet --image
> gcr.io/gcrname/project --platform managed --project 
> --service-account  --memory 256Mi --timeout 300 --concurrency 80 --max-instances 1000 --cpu 1 --clear-env-vars --clear-cloudsql-instances --client-name "Cloud Code for IntelliJ" --client-version 21.2.3-202 --region europe-west2 --allow-unauthenticated

But I am still hoping to see a revision of the plugin to make this simpler...  now back to what I was trying to deploy :)

Comment: The cloud run pycharm plugin not handles this internally.

Comment: Fantastic docker buildx build works like a charm for the problem I faced deploying a Flask App to Google Cloud Run. It inspired me to write an article about my problem - https://torbjornzetterlund.com/build-intel64-compatible-docker-images-from-mac-m1

Comment: Thanks for the Q&A! 
In my case, a new builder wasn't needed! I checked with `docker buildx ls` that the currently selected builder had the capability of `linux/amd64`, so I just went to the build step specifying the platform (ie; `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t ...` and that worked just fine! )